# @Schedule and increating ActiveThreadCount

Tags: jboss, threadpool, ejb-3.1

I have an app that uses EJB JBoss. When I look at "jmx-console/jboss.system/type=ServerInfo" the `ActiveThreadCount` increases each time that the method is called.

This method uses the annotation `@Schedule` to run for a period of twenty seconds. I want to know if there is some way to continue running the method without increasing the `ActiveThreadCount`, or if someone can explain a better alternative to me.